# Within a group check that the last row value is greater than the ones before it

Tags: r, dplyr

Given a dataframe with the following structure, I need a way to check that for each PageID, the CheckDate value for the last dayID ('c' in this case but could be 'd', 'e' or higher) is always greater than 'b' which is always greater than 'a'. I need to return the rows where this in not the case. I'm sure there is a clever dplyr solution but I can't come up with it

here's the data:

```
PageID <-  c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
DayID <- c(letters[1:3], letters[1:3])
CheckDate <-as.POSIXct( c("2017-09-22", "2017-10-07", "2017-11-02", "2017-09-22", "2017-10-07", "2017-11-02") ,tz="UTC")       
df <- data.frame(PageID, DayID, CheckDate)
```

and the dataframe:

```
PageID DayID CheckDate 
1        a     2017-09-22
1        b     2017-10-07
1        c     2017-11-02
2        a     2017-09-22
2        b     2017-10-07
2        c     2017-11-02
```

Comment: Could you add your exact expected outcome?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then

```
df %>% group_by(PageID) %>% summarise(Check = all(diff(CheckDate) > 0))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#   PageID Check
#    <dbl> <lgl>
# 1      1 TRUE 
# 2      2 TRUE
```

does the job. Here for each group of `PageID` I check whether the `CheckDate` vector is strictly increasing.

Comment: This works, but I also need to be able to return these rows. I edited the question to reflect that which I had omitted

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this `tidyverse` solution is what you are after.
Note that I make the assumption, not in the question, that `DayID` is a column of class `"factor"`. And so use `as.integer`to later have `diff` and `>` work.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(PageID) %>%
  mutate(DayID = as.integer(DayID),
         Greater = c(TRUE, diff(DayID) > 0)) %>%
  summarise(Greater = all(Greater))
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#  PageID Greater
#   <dbl> <lgl>  
#1      1 TRUE   
#2      2 TRUE
```